# Best practice to update behaviorsubject object?

Tags: flutter, dart, reactive, rxdart

I can't find anything on the web and most of the examples are with int or string,
I wanted to know if each time I want to update the object on the behavior subject I need to create a new instance of the same object and resend it over the sink, or can I modify the same object and send it again?

example:

```
BehaviorSubject<Data> _behaviorSubject = BehaviorSubject<Data>();


// Example 1
void updateData(Data data, String newName) {
    //will create a new instance
    _behviorSubject.sink.add(data.copyWith(name: newName));
}

//Example 2
// use the same instance
void updateData(Data data, String newName) {
    data.name = newName;
    _behviorSubject.sink.add(data);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: `import 'dart:async';

void main() async {
  var c = StreamController<Foo>();
  c.stream.listen(print);
  var foo = Foo();
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    foo.name = 'item #$i';
    c.add(foo);
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3));
  }
}

class Foo {
  String name;
  toString() => name;
}` - try to run it twice: as it is now and with commented `await Future.delayed(...)`

Comment: @pskink so what are you saying that I should create each time a new instance so i need to use example 1? am I right?

Comment: yes, you should create a new instance

Comment: @pskink Greate Thanks, one more question, if the object is nested Foo has another Object inside him, should I create a new Foo object or it is just enough to update the Inside object by creating a new instance?

Comment: in general you should not be afraid with creating new objects in dart: [Flutter: Don’t Fear the Garbage Collector](https://medium.com/flutter/flutter-dont-fear-the-garbage-collector-d69b3ff1ca30), they say: *"So should Flutter developers fear the garbage collector? With Flutter creating and destroying objects with great frequency, should developers take steps to limit this behavior? It’s not uncommon to see new Flutter developers create references to widgets they know will not change over time, and place them in state so that they won’t be destroyed and rebuilt.
Don’t do this."*

Comment: btw how often your `BehaviorSubject` is updated? 1000s times / second?

Comment: let's say it is a form that using bloc so on every letter it can update the string inside the form object so I would say less than 1s, and thanks for the article!

Comment: less than 1 per second? i though we are talking about thousands... ;-)

Comment: @pskink so you are saying it supposed to know how to handle with intensive allocation, let's say 1000 [times per second]?
And thanks for the help!

Comment: i mean that you should not be afraid with creating one object per second at all, the same with creating 10 or 100 objects... its almost nothing